# How to do cloning of image in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a number of images and I want to drag every image to a certain point or target.

The problem here is that when I drag the image which I want to get the copy or you can say the clone of that image, it should be able to be dragged any number of times whenever I feel like doing so. Currently, that is not the case and I am unable to make out what should be done here further. This is my code :

```
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" ManipulationStarted="abc_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="abc_ManipulationCompleted" x:Name="abc"  Source="/Assets/a.png" MouseLeave="abc_MouseLeave">
       <Image.RenderTransform>
           <CompositeTransform x:Name="ImageTransformation2" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
       </Image.RenderTransform>
       <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
           <toolkit:GestureListener   DragDelta="Image_DragDelta4" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
       </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
   </Image>
```

Appreciate any suggestions or guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to clone your image everytime you drag from it.

Then you won't be able to do that on xaml code. You will have to create a new Image object in you C# code-behind and place it where your original image is placed: this will be your new "base image".

What you will really will be moving will be the image you declared via xaml (at least for the first time).

If you need any more assistance, or if I didn't understand the problem correctly please let me know.